# PPTP with dhcp only for clients

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, pptp

I have a local network at home with a router and a small server. The router manages the local network (DHCP, etc) but does not support PPTP. On the server (Ubuntu 12.04) I set up pptpd and this is working fine ... except that the dhcp3 server started by pptpd is now conflicting with the router. My other systems get answers from two DHCP servers - and not all of them are able to handle it properly (namely my Android tablet).

I have no idea where to start fixing this (except using static IP addresses for my VPN). Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure about your setup, but... is your pptp vpn on a different interface (eg. tun0, tap0, etc) from your host network? You could probably configure pptpd's dhcp server to respond only on the vpn interface.

Normally this is something like an `INTERFACES` setting in `/etc/default/dhcp3-server` or similar, but pptpd might manage its own dhcp server with a different configuration scheme.